# errorUrl in Cordova Config not working on Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

When setting errorUrl in config.xml as described in the [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/), I'll get an error telling me

```
CordovaWebViewImpl: showWebPage: Refusing to load URL into webview since it is not in the <allow-navigation> whitelist. URL=error.html
```

and I'll see the default android error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, changing the url to

```
<preference name="ErrorUrl" value="file:///android_asset/www/error.html" />
```

worked. You should add this value in the android platform section, since this is android specific.

Also make sure to not set

```
 <allow-intent href="*" />
```

otherwise you'll see an error telling you that no activity was found to handle the intent

```
ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
```

If you need to allow web pages as intent, consider adding

`<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />`

instead.

Comment: Hi, does this feature work to replace a HTTP error (ex: 404 error) webview default page by a custom page. I am loading a web site in the InAppBrowser with "_blank" as a target.

Comment: I have  a  Config.xml where i have specified a webapge in content src, but for me the errorUrl value which is an error page is not displayed.HELP!!